# Using multiple custom angular builders

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have been using the `ng-cli-hooks` custom builder for quite some time to inject the CSP into the index.html file and generating a custom webpack config.

Now I am looking into `@ngx-env/builder` to allow environment variables to be injected on build.

But how can I use two or more custom builders? I guess there is no setting in `angular.json`, where I can simply add more than 1 builder, because my search about this has turned up nothing.

But would it be possible to create an own custom builder which then imports functionality from the 2 other builders?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the webpack hook from ng-cli-hooks:
https://github.com/smartin85/ng-cli-hooks#webpackhook

And then I took the functionality from @ngx-env/builder and incorporated it into my webpack.js

You need to install dotenv and dotenv-expand as dependencies in your project.

This is my webpack.js:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const dotenv_expand = require("dotenv-expand");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("node:path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

function getClientEnvironment(prefix) {
  const env = process.env.NG_APP_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV;
  const dotenvBase = path.resolve(process.cwd(), ".env");
  const dotenvFiles = [
    env && `${dotenvBase}.${env}.local`,
    // Don't include `.env.local` for `test` environment
    // since normally you expect tests to produce the same
    // results for everyone
    env && env !== "test" && `${dotenvBase}.local`,
    env && `${dotenvBase}.${env}`,
    dotenvBase
  ].filter(Boolean);
  // Load environment variables from .env* files. Suppress warnings using silent
  // if this file is missing. dotenv will never modify any environment variables
  // that have already been set.  Variable expansion is supported in .env files.
  // https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
  // https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv-expand
  dotenvFiles.forEach((dotenvFile) => {
    if (fs.existsSync(dotenvFile)) {
      dotenv_expand(
        dotenv.config({
          path: dotenvFile
        })
      );
    }
  });
  const processEnv = {
    ...process.env,
    NG_APP_ENV: env
  };
  return Object.keys(processEnv)
    .filter((key) => prefix.test(key))
    .reduce(
      (env, key) => {
        env.raw[key] = processEnv[key];
        env.stringified[key] = JSON.stringify(processEnv[key]);
        return env;
      },
      {
        raw: {},
        stringified: {}
      }
    );
}

module.exports = function (generatedWebpackConfig, options) {
  const { raw, stringified } = getClientEnvironment(/^NG_APP/i);

  generatedWebpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": stringified
    })
  );

  return { ...generatedWebpackConfig };
};
```

Comment: hi @malua , how did you do that?

Comment: hey, I updated my answer to include the full solution. If you have any questions, let me know.